# Disabled ALL USB ports. How do I reenable without PS/2 port on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, bios, operating-systems, ps2

I'm running a Windows 10 Edition and the motherboard's ASUS Z270 motherboard

All USB ports have been disabled via device manaager. I've bought a PS/2 O/P USB I/P adapter, plugged in two USB mice to the PS/2 mouse port; nothing. Doesn't work. One mouse lights up, the other has no response, doesn't even light up.

PS/2 ports and USB enabled in BIOS.

What's left to try? Aside from reinstalling Windows?

I can still work on the computer as I have a Linux partition, but I'm concerned about the files in the Windows partition that I can't access.

Also: I didn't do this, why it's like this answered in comments.

Comment: Remote into the PC.  If that isn't a possibility load of the hive within WinRE and make the required modification to allow the USB device.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how did this happen?  What were you trying to accomplish when you accidentally disabled *all* of the USB ports?

Comment: Tried winre @Ramhound, unless I need a specific version for win10 and had the wrong ver, not sure that's a solution. I'll check with the winre file I was given.

Run5k I didn't do it. A friend was trying to fix a USB issue and from device manager, managed to simultaneously turn all USB ports off.

Comment: Well you made no mention of how you disabled USB my suggestion only works if you disabled it through the registry obviously

Comment: The Z270 board seems to have a native PS/2 port. Why don't you use it?

Comment: After enabling the ps/2 port in bios still not recognized in the OS :/ though it says enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

A few things come to mind, but before I start, I want to point out, that unlike USB, PS/2 ports are not hot-swapable. You need to plug in the cables first, then turn on your computer, or they will not be recognized. Similarly, if you had them plugged in and was working on the computer, if you unplug the cable, then plug them back in, it will not start working again.

So try that first.

You can of course also look for a cheap ps/2 keyboard or mouse to configure it back.

You may be able to go back to a previous restore point to undo the damage

You may also be able to remote into the machine from another computer. If the computer is joined to a domain, there are commandline tools available to start programs on another computer such as psexec. You can copy the files using \pcname\c$ and then launch it using psexec. So you could run teamviewer onto that machine so you can remote into it and undo the damage, would remote desktop not be possible.

Comment: They were plugged in before starting the machine. It's not joined to any network, though it has teamviewer but that's not set to run on boot.

I tried using a USB/ps2 adapter with my mouse (and I checked what type of connector , mouse or keyboard). I will try another ps2 keyboard instead of the usb/ps2 mouse adapter and update.

Comment: It's worth noting that the vast majority of USB => PS/2 ports are dumb (passive) adapters relying on the controller of the device recognising that it's connected to PS/2 (and of course supporting it). I'm not sure how common that is among USB devices these days.

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally have disabled all USB ports by disabling the USB host controller in device manager, one solution is to add an external PCIe USB controller card. Hopefully your existing system driver will be compatible with the PCIe card controller chip. Then connect your mouse and keyboard, and fix the initial problem. Then you can remove the card.

It should be obvious that any USB -> PS/2 adapter won't work because the USB root is disabled.

Actually, the ASUS Z270 board does have a native PS/2 port, so it should be easy to regain control over the PC. But it needs to be done with native PS/2 mouse and/or keyboard, which might be hard to come by. Unfortunately, a passive PS/2 to USB adapter won't work for an arbitrary mouse, it must be a special mouse that supports dual USB/PS/2 interface. Which is also might be difficult to get hold of.

CLARIFICATION: there are two devices on the market that are related to conversion between USB and PS/2. **They both** have a marketing moniker "**USB to PS/2 adapter**", which causes certain confusion. One is to convert a [**PS/2 device to USB plug**](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812196234). This is the one I mentioned first. The other is to [**convert PS/2 port**](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA98C3SU1211) on host computer to adapt an USB mice. In this case the mouse must support dual-mode operations, USB and PS/2. Not every mouse has this support.

Comment: USB is not involved with a USB→PS/2 adapter. If the mouse supports one, it will switch protocols to PS/2.

Comment: @DanielB, if you write "USB->PS/2", then it is all based on USB. Hence it won't work if USB root hub is disabled. If you mean "PS/2 -> USB adapter", then the result will depend on mouse, whether or not it supports the dual mode. But I guess it all depends how you define the connection, as "host-centric", or "device-centric".

Comment: Maybe we’re talking about something different. I’m referring to [these things](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA98C3SU1211). That’s also what the OP is referring to, because everything else wouldn’t make any sense. There is no USB involved, because these adapters are “dumb”. The mouse/keyboard has to support PS/2 explicitly. Some do even without advertising it.

Comment: @DanielB, yes, as I said, the "adapter" definition is host or device-centric. I use host-centric terminology. The OP was vague on which adapter he bought, so I assumed a different one, apparently the wrong one. But you are wrong in assuming that **every** mouse/keyboard "has to support PS/2". They do not. And this is exactly where the OP's assumption is wrong too, and where his problem is. You must have a special mouse. A good indication would be if the mouse package came with this green adapter. If not, it's anyone's bet.

Comment: But that’s exactly what I’m saying: For the adapter I linked to work, the keyboard/mouse has to support PS/2.